# Spree overriding helper method

Tags: helper, spree, overriding

I'm trying to overriding a helper method of base_helper.rb by using this:

```
module Spree
  module BaseHelper.class_eval do

    def taxons_tree(root_taxon, current_taxon, max_level = 1)
      .....
    end

  end
end
```

It's not working for me. Anyone know what I am missing here?

Thank you!

**Fixed:**

I should use:

```
Spree::BaseHelper.module_eval do

    def taxons_tree(root_taxon, current_taxon, max_level = 1)
      ...
    end

end
```

instead.

Comment: For me only worked when used `Spree::BaseHelper.class_eval`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Re-opening the module will work just as well:

```
module Spree
  module BaseHelper
   def taxons_tree(root_taxon, current_taxon, max_level = 1)
      ...
   end
  end
end
```

There's no particular reason to use `class_eval` and `module_eval`, it's just been the habit in the Spree project for a very long time.

Comment: Ryan, where do we put this code. I am in need of overriding `link_to_cart`method to make a customized cart segment. I am coming form PHP and if this is a Rails question, I am sorry but highly appreciate a comment.

Comment: Create a folder under app/helpers, called spree, and put the code from Ryan Bigg into a file caalled base_helper.rb

Comment: @JoaoPereira if you call base_helper.rb, spree won't load the original base_helper.rb. Your would have to copy/paste every function, for it to function properly. But if you call base_helper_decorator.rb, it works.