# Custom Meta Description and Keyword tags in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm trying to modify the default meta descriptions and keyword tags. I'm stuck on this issue, and I don't know spree all that well.

I believe they're being set here: `spree / core / app / helpers / spree / base_helper.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has been tested and is working. Thanks @aledustet for helping me find the solution :)

Create `/app/helpers/spree/base_helper_decorator.rb` and put the following code in there. Do NOT use `/app/helpers/spree/base_helper.rb` as you would have to copy/paste every method in base_helper.rb for it to function properly.

```
module Spree
  module BaseHelper

    def meta_data
      meta = ({
        keywords: "test keyword",
        description: "test description",
      })
    end

  end
end
```

You can also do

```
Spree::BaseHelper.module_eval do
  ....
end
```

I read where others reported this second solution working when the first didn't, so I'm posting both. Both work fine for me.

Per Ryan Bigg: There's no particular reason to use class_eval and module_eval, it's just been the habit in the Spree project for a very long time. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12075315/2229277

At this point you've got control of your meta data, but how about setting it on a controller specific basis? You can do this by creating a private method and calling the helper_method function on it in the controller. Here's a full example that's working and tested:

```
class BrandsController < Spree::StoreController

  helper_method :my_meta_data

  #controller actions here.

  private
  def my_meta_data
    meta = ({
      keywords: "keywords here",
      description: "description here",
    })
  end

end
```

My base helper looks like this, so that it can have some default meta data in case the my_meta_data method is not defined.

```
module Spree
  module BaseHelper

    def meta_data
      if (defined? my_meta_data)
        meta = my_meta_data
      else
        meta = ({
          keywords: "default keywords here",
          description: "default description here",
        })
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use on your second line:

```rb
module Spree
  module  BaseHelper.class_eval 
     ...
  end
end
```

this should work.